# What is the best minifying plugin or tool for wordpress based sites

Tags: wordpress, minify

My Website is built on Wordpress, now I want a plugin or tool to minify all my CSS and JS scripts to one. What is the best known plugin for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm pleased with [css-js-booster](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/css-js-booster/); it's pretty new, but the developer is very responsive and [based on some tests I conducted, the results are nothing short of impressive](http://blog.futtta.be/2010/03/11/speed-up-your-wordpress-site/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the Minify Code. I used this one for my static or handwritten dynamic websites. And with a good experience I decided to use this script within my Wordpress SEO-Blog, too.
There is the Minify code at Google Code.
Some good advices using Minify for Wordpress are explained at [MrClay.org](http://mrclay.org/index.php/2008/03/27/minifying-javascript-and-css-on-mrclayorg/).

I hope my words could help you and you will have success.